# Insert data from table1 to table 2 when table 1 quantity field greater than 0

Tags: java, swing, select, insert, jtable

I have two tables(`lib_book` and `issue_book`). I decrease Quantity value from `lib_book` whenever I issue a book. When Quantity reaches "0", I want to stop inserting in table 2 and show "book not available in library". When I perform this a `NullPointerException` is thrown, and I am not sure how to prevent it.

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

            try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library?allowMultiQueries=true","root","");
                query="select Quantity from lib_book where BookId='"+t1.getText()+"';";
                rs=stmt.executeQuery(query); 
                if(rs.equals("0"))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Book not Available");
                }
                else
                {
                    query="insert into issue_book values('"+t1.getText()+"','"+t2.getText()+"','"+t3.getText()+"','"+t4.getText()+"','"+t5.getText()+"','"+t6.getText()+"','"+l11.getText()+"');";
                    stmt.executeUpdate(query);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Book Issued Successfully");
                    query="update lib_book set Quantity=Quantity-1 where BookId='"+t1.getText()+"';";
                    stmt.executeUpdate(query);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
            }
            showTableData();
            showTable2Data();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

```
rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

returns object of type ResultSet (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html )

To get value of quantity you should use:

```
rs.getInt("Quantity")
```

(with the assumption that 'Quantity' is integer...)

Comment: thanx dzwiedziuu, i did what you said but it still shows "java.lang.NullPointerException"